# Kotlin EditText - Inputing Time AM and PM

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way to include AM or PM within an EditText with inputType of **time**?

I want the user to be capable of selecting between AM or PM when they enter a time in the EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly what you are looking for, but you can display after the `EditText` something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedButton="@id/am"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:selectionRequired="true">

   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/am"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AM"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/pm"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PM"/>

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]

or you can use the `MaterialTimePicker` instead of the `EditText`:

```
        val builder = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(0)
            .setInputMode(MaterialTimePicker.INPUT_MODE_KEYBOARD)
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)

        val picker = builder.build()
        picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
```

[image]